# Is there a way to show datalist options that don't match user input?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got two elements, a `datalist` and an `input`:

```
<datalist id="choices"></datalist>

<input id="custom_id" name="custom_name" type="text" value="" list="choices" class="medium-field"/>
```

Additionally,here is an `AJAX` request, which populates the datalist (this works; not my issue)

```
var params = {
    "partial": $("#custom_id").value;
};
$.ajax({
      cache: true,
      url: "http://www.example.com",
      type: "POST",
      data: JSON.stringify(params),  // contains the input.value
      contentType: "application/json",
      headers: {
        "Range": "0-9"
      },
      dataType: "json",
      processData: false,
      // On success, create <option> elements and append them to datalist
      success: function(data) { .. };
```

The data returned by the REST endpoint is formatted like so:

```
[
  { 
    "label": "active",
    "name": "iron"
  }, 
  ..
]
```

Basically the `AJAX` request hits a REST endpoint in front of a PostgreSQL db that does runs a `SELECT` based on the provided `partial` parameter, and returns a 2-column table (which gets formatted as the above response).

However, I have situations where the data returned from the `AJAX` request is spelled differently from the user's input; for example, when `input.value` = `'magnet'`, I sometimes return a list of options where a few might read `'iron'`.

**The problem** : due to `'iron'` being spelled differently than `'magnet'`, the user won't see this option in the datalist dropdown (even though the option element is created) unless the user *actually types* `'iron'`. Is there a way for me to display `'iron'` in the datalist even though it doesn't match what the user has typed?

Comment: I can't help but think something is missing from this question - any chance you could provide us with the query you hit with your AJAX request, whats an example of the data payload returned when a user types `iron` or `magnet`

Comment: @Alex I've updated the question

Comment: You said that the option isn't showing even though the option is created - how are you filtering this data on the server/client.  There still isn't enough information here

Comment: doesn't sound like using `<datalist>` is the right tool for the job since you have to rely on browser doing the matching

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can understand your question, you are willing to show the synonyms as a result when an input is typed in the search box, i.e if a user types `magnet`, he shall see the synonyms to 'magnet', which in this case happens to be `iron` 
What you can do is when the ajax hit is sent to example.com I understand that there is some SQL code as `SELECT keyword FROM table_name WHERE keyword LIKE '%<whatever string is in data>%'`. This would return 'magnet' even if the user types mag. Now coming to returning 'iron' and 'magnet' when a user types say 'mag'
You will have to modify the table a little bit as follows:
1. Create a keywords table having columns: id, keyword and synonym_to_keyword 
2. Enter the data like 
`(1, 'iron' , null)`
`(2,'magnet',1)`

3. Now modify the query as: `SELECT id as I, keyword FROM table_name WHERE keyword like '%<whatever string is in data>%' OR keyword like (SELECT keyword FROM table_name WHERE synonym_to_keyword = I)`

Note that you will have to maintain a list of keywords and probable synonyms to the keywords so that the user sees all the probable options (like magnet, iron, etc) when he types 'magnet'.

Answer (score 0):

Since Chrome will compare both the value and label to see if it should show the datalist option, you can set all of your option labels to the value you have in your input for them to show up.

[Relevant Chromium patch](https://codereview.chromium.org/2183773003/diff/1/third_party/WebKit/Source/core/html/HTMLInputElement.cpp)

Code Example below:

```js
function autoSuggestAddress(input) {
  if (input.value) {
    // dummy data
    let suggestions = ["Example 1", "Example 2", "Example 3"];
    // clear old datalist
    let datalist = input.list;
    while (datalist.hasChildNodes()) {
      datalist.removeChild(datalist.firstChild);
    }

    suggestions.forEach((item) => {
      let option = document.createElement("option");
      option.label = input.value;
      option.value = item;
      datalist.appendChild(option);
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<form method="GET" id="search-form">
  <label for="address">Address</label>
  <input type="text" id="address" name="address" form="search-form" oninput="autoSuggestAddress(this)" type="search" value="" required autocomplete="off" list="suggestions" />
  <datalist id="suggestions">
  </datalist>
</form>
```